# Add space between \part and \subpart

Tags: exam, parts, white-space

I am using the exam class and I want to increase the space between the part label and the subpart label. I have used the following lines of code which have not helped. I need space where indicated in the image with the red arrow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad (\totalpoints~\points) \hfill 
\vrule depth 0.6cm width 0pt}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.9cm}}   

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\topsep}{0.2cm}}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}

\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
    \part Evaluate the following if \ $\alpha=37^\circ$ \ and        
    \ $\beta=53^\circ$. \ You may use a calculator.
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[2] $\cos 3\alpha$\droppoints
            \fillwithlines{1cm}
        \end{subparts}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your MWE has several errors in it.  However, `\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\topsep}{0.5cm}}` provides what you seek, I think.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the typographical errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this?  I would note the MWE had several typographical errors (missing `}`, missing `\end`, etc.) in it that had to be corrected.

However, what it would appear you are requesting is additional `\topsep` for `subparts`.  In addition, I provided additional `\itemsep` as well, for better vertical symmetry.  Note that code like

```
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\topsep}{0.2cm}}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}
```

is not cumulative.  That is, the second call nullifies the first.  Thus, if you want both these things to occur, the must be combined in a single `\renewcommand`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad (\totalpoints~\points) \hfill 
\vrule depth 0.6cm width 0pt}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.9cm}}  
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\topsep}{0.2cm}\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\topsep}{0.5cm}\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
    \part Evaluate the following if \ $\alpha=37^\circ$ \ and         
    \ $\beta=53^\circ$. \ You may use a calculator.
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[2] $\cos 3\alpha$\droppoints
            \fillwithlines{1cm}
            \subpart[2] $\cos 3\alpha$\droppoints
            \fillwithlines{1cm}
        \end{subparts}
    \part Evaluate the following if \ $\alpha=37^\circ$ \ and        
    \ $\beta=53^\circ$. \ You may use a calculator.
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[2] $\cos 3\alpha$\droppoints
            \fillwithlines{1cm}
        \end{subparts}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]